# Remote XML retrieval

Tags: xml

I'm retrieving a remote XML file with `wget -O remotefile localfile` with a cron tab.

Every so often the local file becomes malformed probably because of double whitespace (according to firefox) between the CDATA tags.

Sometimes the parser gives an error for ' > ' missing, but upon checking the xml file the ' > ' exists...

The remote xml file never gives malformed errors when called in the url.

**EDIT** 
It seems CDATA is not parsed by the xml parser. (w3schools)

Is there a way to set wget to retain wellformed XML?

**If not wget, What is a good way to continously retrieve a remote XML file and keep it well formed?**

Comment: This is not a programming question. Voted to move to SuperUser.

Comment: That's ridiculous. Maybe I'll rephrase the question before I get bombarded.

Comment: @mfusco: perhaps I'm confused - do you mean "wget" the command-line program? Where's the programming question?

Comment: Well regardless of where the question is placed it is more of a programming question rather than, "How do you use this program?"

Comment: What do you mean by "double whitespace between the CDATA tags" (example)? Can't imagine how that could affect well-formedness. Are you asking how to make wget leave the XML as-is? When you say "the parser" are you talking about a part of wget, or some other parser?

Comment: The parser errors are in firefox.

Comment: So... firefox gets these parser errors even when wget is not involved, i.e. by opening the remote URL? or when opening the local file?

Comment: Voting to close, because does not include enough specific information to answer the question.

Comment: @Lars, the local file seems to have a problem. I couldn't really find a solution, so I set the xmlreader open() encoding to read as ISO-5589-1 instead of UTF-8 and haven't encountered problems so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) `http://wherever.com/remote.xml > local.xml`.